# How to refactor this PHP code?

Tags: php, refactoring

Here is my code:

```
$aClass = '';
$bClass = '';
$cClass = '';

if ($_GET['data'] == 'a')
{
    $aClass = ' active';
}
else if ($_GET['data'] == 'b')
{
    $bClass = ' active';
}
else if ($_GET['data'] == 'c')
{
    $cClass = ' active';
}

if ($aClass == '' && $bClass == '' && $cClass == '')
{
    $aClass = ' active';
}
```

Any ideas? This seems messy and redundant.

Comment: The answer to this is of course going to lie within the logic of the system your building. For instance, you could do a `switch` case on the first set, and then leave the `if` statement.

Comment: Note: All of the answers below don't actually require all three variables to be empty, simply that they aren't equal to `a`, `b`, or `c`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `switch-case` construct

```
switch($_GET['data']) {
    case "a": //redundant it is also the default case
        $aClass = ' active';
        break;
    case "b":
        $bClass = ' active';
        break;
    case "c":
        $cClass = ' active';
        break;
    default:
        $aClass = ' active';
}
```

Comment: I can't believe I forgot about switches. Woops. Thanks.

Comment: Happens to the best of us. :D

Comment: @JohnSmith also switch case is better in that switchwation since it has less-less complexity  than many if like you are suing or you can use elseif which would be better than only if

Answer (score 2):

in just 4 lines ;)

```
if ($_GET['data'] == 'b' || $_GET['data'] == 'c')
  ${$_GET['data'] . 'Class'} = ' active';
else
  $aClass = ' active';
```

Comment: Interesting I didn't know you could do that. I think I will go with my currently accepted answer though to help readability for those reading this code in the future.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you're setting a css class.  if so, you could try

```
if ($_GET['data'] == 'b')
{
    $bClass = ' active';
}
else if ($_GET['data'] == 'c')
{
    $cClass = ' active';
}
else
{
    $aClass = ' active';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
switch ($_GET['data']) {
case 'a': $aClass = ' active';
break;
//ETC....
case default: 
$aClass = ' active';
break;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the mod dealing with my flag can see this, but this post had been defaced to look like a question when it was in fact an answer. I have rolled back to the previous revision; my NAA flag is invalid.